# how do I assign a variable based on condition in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

Here is the pseudo code which I would like to write using Robot Framework. If it cannot be done using the framework is there any alternative:

```
${balMethodID}=   Set Variable If  ${balMethodID} == None  ${newBalMethodID}
```

Basically if the value of variable is None then I want to assign a new value. The value of the variable is becoming None when its initial value is not None.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Set Value If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If) can be given two values; the first will be used if the condition is true, the second is if the condition is false. If you want to keep the original value if the condition is false, use the original value as the last argument:

```
${balMethodID}=   Set Variable If  ${balMethodID} == None 
...  # value if true    # value if false 
...  ${newBalMethodID}  ${balMethodID}
```

Comment: This is more robust as it can be reused that I wrote in python. It could be used in Robot file.  `def set_variable_if_no_value_or_none(given_var, to_value):
    if given_var == 'None' or given_var is None or given_var == "":
         return to_value
    else:
         return given_var`